# How can someone check the entire environment for an identical instance of a class in Python?

Tags: python, object, random

I'm creating a program in Python that draws "cards" by creating a random instance of a self-defined `Card` class (i.e. it randomizes the suit and rank to create a new card).

The problem I'm running into is that it's possible for duplicate cards to be generated, sometimes within the same hand. Is there a built-in or standard function for searching the whole local environment for an identical instance of a class (each attribute has the same value)?

If not, I have defined object equality using `__eq__` to mean that the suit and rank are both equal. How can I figure out if a certain class exists within the `local()` dictionary (or within one of its lists), then pull those instances to determine equality?

Comment: You have `locals()` and `globals()`, but the fact that you can create dupicate cards, means you'd have to change your algorithm in the first place. You're probably trying to solve your problem in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going about this all wrong. Instead of trying to search the universe for already-generated cards, make a *deck* of cards and draw cards from that.

```
import random
deck = [Card(suit, number) for suit in suits for number in range(1, 14)]
random.shuffle(deck)

# When you need to draw a card
card = deck.pop()
```